# Rails Hiding a div based on Page using IF and ELSE statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

I have a home page where I want to display a div in a certain way that it will require to be in the top of the application view.

Div is classed as "HOME-BANNER"

I am attempting to create an IF ELSE statement to reflect hiding the div if it is not on the home page.

My question is how do I call the current page in order to identify it as the home view's index.  Also would I end the code or do I place an else statement to continue the rest of the page?

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>WEBSITE</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<% if current_page == "home#index" %>
<div class="HOME-BANNER">


<% end %>


<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="brand">WEBSITE</a>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><%= link_to "All Jobs", jobs_path %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "My Profile", tempers_path %></li>

                </ul>

                <div class="float-right">

                    <div class="btn-group open">
                          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i></a>
                          <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="caret"></span></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><i class="icon-pencil"></i><a href="<%= link_to '', edit_user_registration_path %>"> My Profile</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-th-large"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-th-list"></i> My Posts</a></li>
                            <li><a href=""><i class="icon-th-list"></i> My Searches</a></li>
                            <li><i class="icon-stop"></i> <%= link_to ' Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
                          </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container"> 

    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>


    <%= yield %>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to do this from your controller. Since this is a localized event, use the controller that specifically hosts this View and not your application controller.

```
def whatever_view_this_is
  @home_banner  = true
end
```

Then in your view :

```
<% if @home_banner %>
  <div class="HOME-BANNER">
<% end %>
```

Comment: AMAZING! Works perfectly. Still new to rails, trying to catch up as quickly as possible.

Comment: You'll pick it up quickly with that attitude. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks!  One quick question - if you have a Admin, User, Guest sort of layout would you recommend the same sort of layout in the controller, or create new controllers, views and routes?

Comment: Hmm.. this gets really artistic, and it also has a lot to do with how the entire app works. Try to think of it in terms of "what needs to be accomplished here". If that general action can be shared between all three roles, than keep one view, and differentiate them inside the view. This will help you keep your code and thoughts organized